# How to read integers from a file that are separated with semi colon?

Tags: java, io

So in my codes, I am trying to read a file that is like:

```
100
22
123;22
123 342;432
```

but when it outputs it would include the ";" ( ex. 100,22,123;22,123,342;432} ).
I am trying to make the file into an array ( ex. {100,22,123,22,123...} ).
Is there a way to read the file, but ignore the semicolons?
Thanks!

```
    public static void main(String args [])
{
    String[] inFile = readFiles("ElevatorConfig.txt");
    for ( int i = 0; i <inFile.length; i = i + 1)
    {
        System.out.println(inFile[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inFile));
}
public static String[] readFiles(String file)
{
    int ctr = 0;
    try{
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File(file));
        while (s1.hasNextLine()){
            ctr = ctr + 1;
            s1.next();

        }
        String[] words = new String[ctr];
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File(file));
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < ctr ; i = i + 1){
            words[i] = s2.next();


        }
        return words;
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't want to ignore semicolons, you want to treat them as separators just like spaces. Ignoring the semicolon in `123;22` would make it `12322`

Comment: BTW never pretend an Exception didn't happen just to get the code to compile. Only handle an Exception when you are going to do something useful with it.

Comment: Try nextInt() instead of just next()

Comment: Where possible, only read a file once. You can use an `ArrayLIst<String>` instead of a `String[]` and only parse the file once.

Comment: @J.L.Louis that will blow up on the first semicolon.

Comment: I didn't mean that to be the whole solution. You would have to read the non numerical characters out of the buffer after reading each number.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static String[] readFiles(String file)
{
    int ctr = 0;
    try{
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File(file));
        while (s1.hasNextLine()){
            ctr = ctr + 1;
            s1.next();

        }
        String[] words = new String[ctr];
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File(file));
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < ctr ; i = i + 1){
            words[i] = s2.next();


        }
        return words;
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Replace this by

public static String[] readFiles(String file) {

```
 List<String> retList = new ArrayList<String>();
  Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File(file));
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < ctr ; i = i + 1){
         String temp = s2.next();
         String[] tempArr = se.split(";");
         for(int k=0;k<tempArr.length;k++) {
             retList.add(tempArr[k]);

         }
}

return (String[]) retList.toArray();
```

}

Comment: The OP wants `123;22` to become `123` and `22`

Answer (score 0):

Use regex. Read the entire file into a String *(read each token as a String and append a blank space after each token in the String)* and then split it at blank spaces and semi colons.

```
String x <--- contains all contents of the file
String[] words = x.split("[\\s\\;]+");
```

The contents of `words[]` are:

```
"100", "22", "123", "22", "123", "342", "432"
```

Remember to parse them to `int` before using as numbers.

Comment: I did something similar to this, but instead of reading the entire file. It would just read the last line. If I printed out the array, it would just be the last line in each element.

Comment: @TheEWL Fine. Read whatever you want and then use the split statement.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to use BufferedReader Read line by line then split by ;

```
public static String[] readFiles(String file)
{
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    line = br.readLine();
}
 String allfilestring = sb.toString();
 String[]  array = allfilestring.split(";");

return array;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` to split the string into array according to your requirement using regex.

```
String s; // string you have read from the file
String[] s1 = s.split(" |;"); // s1 contains the strings separated by space and ";"
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Keep the code for counting the size of the array.
I would just change the way you input your values.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ctr; i++) {
       words[i] = "" + s1.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to replace all non digit characters in your complete file string with a space.  That way any non number character is ignored.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    line = br.readLine();
}

String str = sb.toString();
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+"," ");
```

Now you have a string with numbers separated by spaces, we can tokenize them into number strings.

`String[] final = str.split("\\s+");`

then convert to int datatypes.